# array created from dynamic fields in objects on JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to write a function that will generate table columns based on dynamic data that comes from the server. Conditionally comes an array of objects, inside which there are fields that may differ:

```
{
 {
  id:1,
  water: 'water',
 }
 {
  id:2,
  fire: 'fire',
  earth: 'earth'
 }
}
```

. And I need to form one final data array with all these fields at the output (conditionally there are 2 objects, one has the WATER field, and the other has the FIRE and EARTH field, and the output should get one array named data, which has the fields: FIRE, EARTH and WATER). I tried to formulate, but if you have questions, I will try to write more in more detail.

Comment: Please give the desired output. You are talking about array of object, can you give us an example of that array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [
    {
     id:1,
     water: 'water',
    },
    {
     id:2,
     fire: 'fire',
     earth: 'earth'
    }
];

function generateColumns(data) {
  const columns = [];
  data.forEach((item) => {
    Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => {
      if (!columns.includes(key) && key !== 'id') {
        columns.push(key);
      }
    });
  });
  return columns;
}

const columns = generateColumns(data);

console.log(columns);
```